# Calling Bool on a Regex does not work as documented

Tags: regex, oop, raku

According to [the documentation](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Regex#method_Bool), `Bool` method of `Regex` class...

> Matches against the caller's $_ variable, and returns True for a match or False for no match.

However, in this example

```
$_ = "3";
my regex decimal { \d };
say &decimal.Bool;
```

returns `False`. Also, [looking at the source](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/cbb9034a08b0423f40d8a070f1c24a9ed7e74527/src/core/Regex.pm6#L85-L92), it kinda makes sense what it says, since it will be matching a `$!topic` instance variable. Not clear, however, that this variable will effectively correspond to $_, and the example above seems to say so. Any idea of what actually happens?

Comment: For me, [using Rakudo 2018.12 on tio.run](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/18lXsFWQclYyZort1KhKDU9tUIhJTU5MzcxR6FaISZFodaaqzixUkENKqjnlJ@fY/3/PwA), it works.

Comment: Looks like there was a change of semantics in https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/commit/8ef7c15ed5bff6674270dfe209962aaafd0ac825

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short answer: the documentation was sort of accurate for 6.c, however the exact semantics were not at all so straightforward as "the caller" (and in fact, contained a risk of really odd bugs). The refined behavior is:

- Anonymous regexes constructed with forms like `/.../` and `rx:i/.../` will capture the `$_` and `$/` at the point they are reached in the code (populating the `$!topic` variable mentioned in the question).
- `Bool` and `sink` will cause a match against that captured `$_`, and will store the resulting `Match` object into that `$/`, provided it is writable.

Since this behavior only applies to anonymous regexes, you'd need to write:

```
$_ = "3";
my regex decimal { \d };
say /<&decimal>/.Bool;
```

Here's the long answer. The goal of the `Bool`-causes-matching behavior in the first place was for things like this to work:

```
for $file-handle.lines {
    .say if /^ \d+ ':'/;
}
```

Here, the `for` loop populates the topic variable `$_`, and the `if` provides a boolean context. The original design was that `.Bool` would look at the `$_` of the caller. However, there were a number of problems with that. Consider:

```
for $file-handle.lines {
    .say if not /^ \d+ ':'/;
}
```

In this case, `not` is the caller of `.Bool` on the `Regex`. However, `not` would also have its own `$_`, which - as in any subroutine - would be initialized to `Any`. Thus in theory, the matching would not work. Apart from it did, because what was actually implemented was to walk through the callers until one was found with a `$_` that contained a defined value! This is as bad as it sounds. Consider a case like:

```
sub foo() {
    $_ = some-call-that-might-return-an-undefiend-value();
    if /(\d+)/ {
        # do stuff
    }
}
$_ = 'abc123';
foo();
```

In the case that the call inside of `foo` were to return an undefiend value - perhaps unexpectedly - the matching would have continued walking the caller chain and instead found the value of `$_` in the caller of `foo`. We could in fact have walked many levels deep in the call stack! (Aside: yes, this also meant there was complications around which `$/` to update with results too!)

The previous behavior also demanded that `$_` have dynamic scope - that is, to be available for callers to look up. However, a variable having dynamic scope prevents numerous analyses (both the compiler's and the programmer's ones) and thus optimizations. With many idioms using `$_`, this seemed undesirable (nobody wants to see Perl 6 performance guides suggesting "don't use `with foo() { .bar }` in hot code, use `with foo() -> $x { $x.bar }` instead"). Thus, `6.d` changed `$_` to be a regular lexical variable.

That 6.d `$_` scoping change had fairly little real-world fallout, but it did cause the semantics of `.Bool` and `.sink` on `Regex` to be examined, since they were the one frequently used thing that relied on `$_` being dynamic. That in turn shed light on the "first defined `$_`" behavior I just described - at which point, the use of dynamic scoping started to look more of a danger than a benefit!

The new semantics mean the programmer writing an anonymous regex can rely on it matching the `$_` and updating the `$/` that are visible in the scope they wrote the regex - which seems rather simpler to explain, and - in the case they end up with a `$_` that isn't defined - a lot less surprising!